How to configure webpack.config.ts @angular-builders/custom-webpack Angular 18
I am using an Angular 18 project and @angular-builders/custom-webpack@18 for the custom Webpack configuration. The issue I am facing is that I am developing a web component that uses an image, and I need to publish this web component as an npm package.
The image is present in public/assets, and I referenced it in the src attribute of the img tag. It works fine locally, but when I published it to an npm package and used it in another React project, the images are not visible because the path I mentioned is looking for the image in the project root folder instead of inside the package.
So I came across the idea to use @angular-builders/custom-webpack, which has an extra Webpack config option, allowing us to use asset/resource and other asset modules in Webpack.
src="./assets/jobs.png" works in local
when i add the config file it runs but the build folder doesn't contain the images folder
webpack.config.ts
import * as webpack from 'webpack';
import { CustomWebpackBrowserSchema, TargetOptions } from '@angular-builders/custom-webpack';
export default (
  config: webpack.Configuration,
  options: CustomWebpackBrowserSchema,
  targetOptions: TargetOptions) => {
    if (config.module && config.module.rules) {
      config.module.rules.unshift(
        {
          test: /\.(png|jpg)$/i,
          type: 'asset/resource',
          parser: {
            dataUrlCondition: {
              maxSize: 5 * 1024 // Inline images under 10KB
            }
        },
        generator: {
            filename: 'images/[name]-[hash][ext]'
          }
        }
      );
      console.log(config.module)
}
  
  return config;
}

angular.json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "angular-web-component": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/angular-web-component",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main":"src/main.ts",
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./webpack.config.ts",
              "replaceDuplicatePlugins": true,
              "mergeStrategies": { "externals": "replace" }
            },
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "/assets"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kB",
                  "maximumError": "1MB"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kB",
                  "maximumError": "4kB"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "angular-web-component:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "angular-web-component:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n"
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "public"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    },

here I mentioned config path correctly
"customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./webpack.config.ts",
              "replaceDuplicatePlugins": true,
              "mergeStrategies": { "externals": "replace" }
            },

I used asset/resource and asset/inline both not worked
Can anyone know about where i am doing worng
I am trying to bundle the images with the package or build with the help of @angular-builders/custom-webpack on Angular 18, but the assets module in Webpack is not properly working (asset/resource and asset/inline). We can use base64 encoding ourselves, but I think bundling is the right way.

The config file angular.json only copy files from src/assets to dist folder, if you image was in public/assets folder, it won't be bundled to the build.
"assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "/assets"
              }
            ],


You can eithter put your images to src/assets folder instead of public/assets folder, or set asset path for public/assets to angular.json
